# Angular2 sobreescribir un provider en un test que ha sido inyectado directamente en el componente

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Estoy tratando de testear un componente que pide que le inyecten dos servicios, uno está declarado en el app.module y el otro directamente en el componente.

En el primer caso la sobreescritura funciona perfectamente pero, en el segundo, no funciona y llama al servicio real en lugar de al mockeado.

Este sería el test:

```
describe('DoneComponent', () => {
  let component: DoneComponent
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DoneComponent>

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        DoneComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ],
      providers: [
        {provide: ServerService, useClass: ServerServiceMock},
        {provide: AppService, useClass: AppServiceMock}
      ]
    }).compileComponents()
  }))

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DoneComponent)
    component = fixture.componentInstance
    fixture.detectChanges()
  })

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy()
  })
})
```

AppServiceMock funciona perfectamente pero ServerServiceMock no y se debe a que ServerService no está declarado en app.module como AppService si no directamente en done.component. Si lo declaro en app.module funciona ¿De qué manera se debería hacer para que funcionara?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Se que es lo fácil pero... Por qué no declaras el servicio como externo? No creo que sea para nada una buena práctica y casi con total seguridad no hay un caso de uso donde solo se pueda exponer dentro del componente y no fuera... pero bueno, eso ya depende de tu app y de tus requerimientos.

Comment: tuve que cambiar el servicio para que con una instancia fuera suficiente, pero tiene que haber alguna forma, ya que si no no habria opcion de poner providers propios en cada componente y estarían solo en el app.module

Comment: Ya no se usa el provider en el decorator del componente, se una en el ngModule, y puedes (y DEBES) de tener más de un app module, y así inyectar en tu ngModule los providers necesarios. Por eso te digo que la forma que estas haciendo de declarar el servicio en el componente es una mala práctica, que a la larga dará problemas (de hecho incluso te lo da ya) así que no creo que haya forma de hacerlo, más bien creo que no es la forma de hacerlo. Salu2

Comment: tienes algún ejemplo de como tener varios app.module? Gracias!

Comment: ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?

Comment: La solución fue no usarlo y meterlo dentro del app.module